# What does "among other things" mean?

Tags: meaning

> Signals to be used to, among other things, halt working in the event
>   of lost communications or inability to utilize radios.

In the sentence above, does "among other things" mean "along with other purposes"? Does it mean "Signals to be used to halt working ...(along with other purposes other than halting)"? It's unclear for me what "other things" it refers to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Among other things** is an expression meaning that the activity/example/phenomenon being described is just one of a number of related activities or examples.

The sentence tells us explicitly that signals would cease under two conditions (the loss of communications and non-functioning radios). It adds **among other things** to tell us that signals were also subject to other influences that might affect their clarity and strength.

It does not tell us what these influences are. It merely indicates that there are other considerations to be taken into account.

Your sentence appears to contain extra words: Presumably it should read: **Signals used to.....** and NOT "Signals to be used to....

Googling **among other things** will give you numerous explanations and examples of its use.

https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/among-other-things_2

Comment: I think it's about signals to be used for various purposes, **including** the halting of work, when other means of communication (including radio) are not working. Think semaphore flags, Aldis lamps, flares, sirens, etc.

Comment: True, a more apt interpretation!

Comment: Before the days of electronics, a 'signal' was something visual - a lamp, a flag, a flare, etc. or the message thus conveyed.

Answer (score 0):

This is a form of "plain English" expression that supplanted the use, by the "classically educated", of the Latin expression *[inter alia](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/inter-alia)*. A lot of English-use abbreviations are for such Latin phrases - *[QED](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/qed)*, *[n.b.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nota_bene)*, *[etc.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/etc)*, *[et al.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/et-al)* (that one is *et alia*, same sense of *alia*), *[e.g.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/eg)*, *[cf.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cf.)*, and probably more but that are the ones that come to mind.

It is used with a list, either before or after, to indicate that the list is not *exhaustive*, or complete. It means that, in this case, the signals will be used for things other than those mentioned in the list - but will be used for things in the list.